# How to connect to an API on the host machine from the CM/CD on docker?

Tags: docker

Looking at https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/ it says

> I want to connect from a container to a service on the host The host
> has a changing IP address, or none if you have no network access. We
> recommend that you connect to the special DNS name
> `host.docker.internal` which resolves to the internal IP address used by
> the host.

When I try this I get "The remote name could not be resolved".

I found this open [issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1976) which has a script to map the network gateway port to the `host.docker.internal` but this just results in "Unable to connect to the remote server".

Comment: Seem to recall having a similar issue a while back. Please can you try running the following on host machine CMD => hostname. Then using the result.

Comment: Running the following what?

Comment: If you open command prompt and type 'hostname' it will output a value for for your computer name like 'dean-desktop-abc'. I was then able to use that as domain, when calling host machine from within docker container.

Comment: @DeanOBrien that `hostname` trick is a gamechanger. Works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue. `host.docker.internal` is available on identity, solr, but is not available on cm, sql containers.

You have a few options:

1. You can [use ngrok](https://exdst.com/posts/20230521-ngrok-sitecore-containers)
2. You can update your [container manually by running this script](https://exdst.com/posts/20230525-host-docker-internal-sitecore-containers):

```
# host.docker.internal is not available on CM, so we need to add it manually
$containerId = docker ps --filter ancestor=jss_astro-xm1-cm --format "{{.ID}}"
$ip = Get-NetIPAddress | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.IPAddress.StartsWith("192")}
$ipAddress = $ip.IPAddress
Write-Host "Adding DNS record to container $containerId. Host: host.docker.internal. IP: $ipAddress"
$command = "'$ipAddress host.docker.internal' | Out-File -Append -Encoding ASCII -FilePath '$($Env:windir)\system32\drivers\etc\hosts'"
docker exec -it $containerId powershell $command
```

This script will add a record to the CM container `hosts` file. And point `host.docker.internal` to your host IP address.

---

P.S.
I expected that it should be fixed in [Docker 4.19](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/), according to release notes: "Reverted to fully patching etc/hosts on Windows (includes host.docker.internal and gateway.docker.internal again). For WSL, this behavior is controlled by a new setting in the General tab. Fixes docker/for-win#13388 and docker/for-win#13398."

But the issue is still there. And it requires deeper investigation: why does it work in the Identity container but fail on CM?

Comment: Root cause of it failing on CM is here https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1976#issuecomment-543176154

Comment: Thanks, your method is the only one I have got to work. On my network though it is an IP address with 10.x not 192.x so made that small change.

Comment: Thanks for the tip that identity server does work, it helped me diagnose what the correct IP should be.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying the containers `hosts` files, you should be able to just reference your docker host name directly. In my case, I wanted to set my `CM` `Server side rendering engine endpoint URL` to point to my `Next.JS` site which was running on my docker host machine.

Start by running this on your host machine:

`hostname`

Then take that value and updat the value of that field to:

`http://<HOSTNAME>:3000/api/editing/render`

This should save you from future issues in case your Docker host machine IP changes due to usage of VPNs/etc.

This will also work, but it may stop working if/when your Docker host IP changes:

`http://<DOCKER_HOST_IP_ADDRESS>:3000/api/editing/render`

You can also experiment with this Docker setting, although in my experience, it doesn't work with some Windows containers.

[image: docker setting for hosts file mod]