# Local CM site Experience Editor fetches NextJS static assets from Vercel instead of local

Tags: experience-editor, docker, nextjs, vercel

I have a local install of NextJS & SC 10.2. The site is running via docker with a setup that is mostly similar to this example:
https://github.com/Sitecore/docker-examples/blob/develop/getting-started/docker-compose.yml

My local endpoints are:

- `cd.mysite.localhost`
- `cm.mysite.localhost`
- `id.mysite.localhost`
- `hrz.mysite.localhost`

I can also view the site via `localhost:3000`. On that endpoint, I see the static assets correctly being loaded from my local:

[image: localhost asset sources]

However, when I view my CM site in Experience Editor, the static assets are instead fetched from an upstream publicly accessible Vercel endpoint rather than from my local development endpoint.

[image: Vercel static assets]

This source corresponds to a historical Vercel build preview site. I have searched extensively for where this endpoint might be originating from. As far as I can tell, it's not referenced in any of my local code, docker compose files, configs, environment files, and I found no hits when text searching the `inetpub` directory of the CM container.

I also added this Sitecore config change, but the results are still the same.

```xml
<app 
  name="MySite" 
  serverSideRenderingEngine="http" 
  serverSideRenderingEngineEndpointUrl="http://localhost:3000/api/editing/render" 
  serverSideRenderingEngineApplicationUrl="http://localhost:3000"/>
```

Where might the Vercel endpoint be coming from, and which config/environment settings must be adjusted to use my local assets instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Editing Host Configuration

In SXA (< 10.3) and Headless SXA (> 10.3 or XM Cloud) you configure your Editing Host within the Site Settings item.

`/sitecore/content/<<Site Collection Name>>/<<Site Name>>/Settings`

The fields of interest to you are:

- Server side rendering engine endpoint URL
- ServerSideRenderingEngineApplicationUrl

[image: server side rendering engine fields]

### Additional Resources

- https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/201/sitecore-headless-development/walkthrough--configuring-the-http-rendering-engine-for-your-jss-app.html
- [How to connect to an API on the host machine from the CM/CD on docker?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/35037/how-to-connect-to-an-api-on-the-host-machine-from-the-cm-cd-on-docker)
- https://exdst.com/posts/20230525-host-docker-internal-sitecore-containers
- https://exdst.com/posts/20230521-ngrok-sitecore-containers