# Back-end developer full local setup with monorepo

Tags: xm-cloud, rendering-host

I'm curious if anyone has had a similar idea of using Traefik as a reverse proxy, and then having "dummy" rendering/editing hosts that point to a locally running head through a proxy. During our build, we've learned it's not smart to try and use a monorepo, i.e. TurboRepo or NX with Windows containers. We have a ticket open on this but it hasn't gotten much traction. Does anyone know if like this would even be possible?

[image]

I have tried configuring Traefik as a reverse proxy to test this scenario, but additional work will be necessary to configure the environment in this way.

For more information on using monorepos with XM Cloud, see the following notes I've compiled over the last couple of weeks:

I'm trying to expose an annoying issue with a full local setup of XM Cloud with dockerized internal rendering/editing hosts. We are aware of various permutations available for connecting the head, running on http://localhost:3000, to higher XM Cloud environments, and this is a great solution for our front-end engineers.

- https://www.sergevandenoever.nl/static/72ec93a12d0b637aa91d8faaad544f0b/8740f/local_dev_against_cm.excalidraw.png
- https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/connect-xm-cloud-pages-to-your-local-xm-instance.html

Unfortunately, back-end engineers often need a full local setup to maximize efficiency, and when your front-end team has chosen to use modern monorepos using npm workspaces, this is currently not possible. To boil this down, Turbo and NX do not seem to work within Windows containers without heavy workarounds. If you would like to go down this road, here are some links describing the problems you will run into:

- https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/52244
- [XM Cloud with NPM workspaces on local Docker throws "Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink"](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/36937/xm-cloud-with-npm-workspaces-on-local-docker-throws-error-eperm-operation-not)